# Risks with importing files from another directory in python

Tags: python

I have this structure of files (directory and after arrow files)

model1 -> model1_main.py, ...
model2 -> model2_main.py, ...
main -> main.py, ...

I need to call each of the models in main.py

I am aware of two methods to import files from another directory in

/main

main.py

Method1

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../model1/model1_main.py')

import model1_main
```

method2

```
import importlib.machinery

loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('model1', '../model1/model1_main.py')
model1 = loader.load_module('model1')

model1.mainFunction(parameter)
```

What are the unforeseen risk with either method ?

Comment: It is important to note that invoking a python script does not make the location of that script the current working directory.  So relative paths in this case is a very bad idea.

Comment: If you need to specify locations relative to where a given script is located, you could use the \_\_file\_\_ variable to find where the script is and then construct the correct path from there using the os.path commands.

Comment: Also you don't want to insert '../model1/model1_main.py' into the path.  You just want to insert '../model1'.

Comment: Instead of adding `model1/model1_main.py` to `sys.path`, you should add `..` and import the modules as `import model1.model1_main`. That will allow you to import all of the modules, and only have to add one directory to sys.path

Comment: Of course, you probably should be organizing the code differently anyway.  If you include it all under one module, then you don't need to be playing with sys.path at all.  If you make you have a myprog directory that has a \_\_init\_\_.py file in it then you put your "main" code in \_\_main\_\_.py and have your model code in the \_\_init\_\_.py files in subdirectories model1 and model2 of myprog.  Then your  \_\_main\_\_.py file just needs to "import .model1" for example.